# Hover effect on text under an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't apply a hover effect on the text under the image, or on the image itself.

here's the code (CSS):

```
#photo {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.img-with-text {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 200px;
}



.img-with-text img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

how can apply some hover effects?

Comment: I don't see any `:hover` here

Comment: You should upload your relevant code to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: what I mean is, I don't know where to put it. 
I created a div and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.img-with-text {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 200px;
    display:block;
}

.img-with-text:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: how come?? Can you tell me what happening? Tell me what do you want the text to be when you hover your mouse over it>

Comment: the text should be underlined and has a background color.

Comment: can you do a fiddle of this??

Comment: IT WORKED! thank you. Now all I have to do is to make it clickable.

Comment: can I use the 

.img-with-text:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

for link, visited and active?

Comment: yes you can using the filter. Learn more about them. Refer a good book like CSS3 the missing manual

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZQK/68/)**

**CSS**

```
#hover {
    display: none;
}

#image:hover + #hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the text in `<a href="#">your text</a>` tag or use JQuery

```
$("p").hover(
function () {

}
);
```

hover effect on image.

```
$("#photo").hover(
    function () {

    }
    );
```

Comment: sorry but we are not allowed to use javascript.

Comment: if you need the hover effect on text omly try .<a href="#">your text</a>.